# Trying to convert jQuery get request into parseable object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse a jQuery get request into an object or some other way of getting a particular div on a page.

Here's my code:

```
  $.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghanistan", function(response) {
      var elements;

      elements = $.html(response);
      console.log(elements);
  });
```

The only problem is that elements is not `HTML` to parse. Let's say I want to get a specific `div` on the response variable - how would I go about doing that? This is with the intention of (eventually, after some processing) copying it to a `div` on my local page.

Don't worry about cross domain issues - this is for a Phonegap application

Comment: Doesn't Wikipedia have a JSON API you can use?  EDIT: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page or http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Comment: Not seeing an easy way to just grab the HTML - the API seems to give the Wiki format data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.parseHTML()` so you can convert that response to a set of DOM nodes  and later insert that to the document.

You can do it like this:

```
 $.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghanistan", function(response) {
    var elements;
    elements = $.parseHTML(response);
    console.log(elements);
    var myDiv = $(elements).find('#idForDiv');
});
```

Comment: Did you actually test this? I'm not sure this is feasible considering the CORS error. EDIT - sorry just saw OP's statement about cross domain issues.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the jQuery load function does exactly what you want. You can specify a selector after the url to load a particular part of the page:

```
$("#mydiv").load( "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghanistan #divonpage");
```

http://jqapi.com/#p=load

Answer (score 0):

If the response from the server is HTML then you can wrap it in a jQuery object and act upon it.

I would vouch for this approach:

```js
var server_response = '<div style="background-color:yellow;"><div class="find-me">Hello</div></div>';

$('span').html($(server_response).find('.find-me'));
```

```css
.find-me {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```